# Fluentd and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, fluentd

1) I have set of logs in one location, I am able to get the data using fluentd output plugin, Is there a way to FORWARD the logs to spark?

2) I have connected the Spark to **Cassandra** using Spark Cassandra connector jar, I know the data location of Cassandra but what is the data location of spark and in which port Apache spark is running?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry